# apache pig, store result in a txt file

Tags: text, apache-pig, store

Hello i'm a new PIG user, 
I'm trying to stock some data in a txt file but when i'm using the STORE command, it creates a folder that contains the following files : _SUCCESS and part-r-00000.

How to get this result in a txt file ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `STORE` output usually look like.
You can run Hadoop fs command from inside pig so you can write something like the below inside your pig (see the documentation [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cmds.html#fs))

```
fs -getmerge /my/hdfs/output/dir/* /my/local/dir/result.txt
fs -copyFromLocal /my/local/dir/result.txt /my/hdfs/other/output/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the files using cat command and pipe the output to .txt file using put command

```
hadoop fs -cat /in_dir/part-* | hadoop fs -put - /out_dir/output.txt
```

or

Merge the files in the folder using the getmerge command to the output .txt file

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /in_dir/ /out_dir/output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way, map reduce job writes the output.

As Pig runs map-reduce job internally so job writes output in the form of part files :
**part-m-00000**(map  output) or **part-r-00000**(reduce output).

Let's say you are giving following output dir("**/user/output1.txt**") in your script, so it will have:

```
/user/output1.txt/part-r-00000  
/user/output1.txt/_SUCCESS
```

There may be multiple part files created inside output1.txt, so in that case you can merge those into one.

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /user/output1.txt/* /localdir/output/result.txt
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /localdir/output/result.txt /user/output/result.txt
```